# Initialize random constant values in ctor

Tags: c++, c++11, random, constructor

In my class there appeared necessity to initialize some constant random values in sructure.

To achieve this there are defined limits:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 eng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> lim1(3, 6);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> lim2(7, 20);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> lim3(1000, 100000);
```

And following structure:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned        c1, c2, c3;
    const unsigned  limc1 = lim1(eng), 
                    limc2 = lim2(eng), 
                    limc3 = lim3(eng);
} CTR;
```

So, when I try to do some initialization with these values

```
class Foo {
    private:
        CTR ctr;
    public:
    voud initializeCTR(CTR &ctr);
};
```

The problem is that field `ctr` invisible for `initializeCTR()`

```
Foo foo;
foo.initializeCTR(ctr); <- ctr undefined here
```

How should I code ctor or something other to achieve different random values for all class instances?

Comment: What is `initializeCTR` supposed to do? Does it need to work with two instances of `CTR` (one passed as a parameter, and one a member of `Foo`)? It seems that you didn't actually mean to have both (or else you wouldn't have been confused by the client lacking the second instance, and perhaps would have known enough not to give the two the same name).

Comment: Using `typedef struct` is not useful in C++. You can directly use `struct CTR`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
Foo foo;
foo.initializeCTR(ctr); <- ctr undefined here
```

The variable `ctr` you are trying to access is not the private field `ctr` defined in class `Foo`. A solution should be:

```
void Foo::initializeCTR() {
  ctr.do_something();
  // ...
}
```

A better solution is to use it in the constructor:

```
Foo::Foo() {
  ctr.do_something();
  // ...
}
```